# Viewing EventSource activity duration in Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: c#, etw, perfview

I've been playing around with ETW and some custom events based on [System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28567). It's all working nicely with the TPL, meaning I'm getting correlated activities even across different threads - all very nice. I am using [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to validate this is working correctly.

I'd now like to start using [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn927305(v=vs.85).aspx) in my analysis, but I can't see how to get anything resembling an activity duration displayed in a data table - something like the DURATION_MSEC computed column in [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=28567). I've noticed that duration is available as a tooltip on the Generic Events graph, so it would appear that this information is available in the tool.

Does anyone know how to set this up in [WPA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn927305(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: for viewing raw events I always use Perfview to see this easily. But to analyze CPU;DISK, Memory issues, the graphs from WPA are better. In the "View Editor" there are ways to add filters, maybe there is a way to do this, but MS never really published a good documentation about WPA.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the advise - will fall back to Perfview for this sort of analysis then. It's a shame, but agree that documentation is challenging to find, at best.

Comment: Just came across my own question after being away from this stuff for a bit. Disappointed how lacking the documentation is for WPA.